# Show that $\,a_n=f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n)-\int_1^n f(x)\,dx\,\,$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\,f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb R\,$ be a decreasing and lower bounded function. Show that the sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined as:
$$
a_n=f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n)-\!\int_1^n\!\! f(x)\,dx,
$$
is convergent.

Thanks for you reply in advance.

Comment: Draw a picture. And/or look up the integral test of convergence and its proof.

Comment: To test the convergence of this sequence I need to take into consideration that its decreasing. I know that the limit of a decreasing function thats at the same time inferiorly limited, is equal to its infimum. But the problem is I have nothing. So can you show me something more precise or just a hint , please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume that $f(x)\ge M$.

Since $f$ is decreasing then $f(k)\ge f(x)$, for all $x\in [k,k+1]$, and hence
$$
 f(k)=f(k)\int_k^{k+1}1\,dx=\int_k^{k+1}f(k)\,dx\ge \int_{k}^{k+1} f(x)\,dx,
$$
and hence
$$
 f(1)+\cdots+f(n)\ge \int_1^{n+1} f(x)\,dx
$$
and thus
$$
a_n= f(1)+\cdots+f(n) -\int_1^n f(x)\,dx\ge \int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,dx\ge M.
$$
Also $a_n=f(1)+\cdots+f(n) -\int_1^n f(x)$ is decreasing as
$$
a_{n+1}-a_n=f(n+1)-\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,dx\le 0.
$$
So $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing and lower bounded, and hence convergent.

Comment: "Also $a_n$ is decreasing as $a_{n+1}-a_n=\ldots\geq 0$."  Isn't the sense on that backwards? You've just argued that $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$.  I _think_ you want $\leq 0$ at the end of that inequality.

Comment: I made the correction.

Comment: Can you please explain me why is $f(k)\ge \int_{k}^{k+1} f(x)\,dx$

Comment: See my explanation in the new version of the answer.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis S.Smyrlis And excuse me, but its the last one: Why $f(k)=f(k)\int_k^{k+1}1\,dx=\int_k^{k+1}f(k)\,dx\ge \int_{k}^{k+1} f(x)\,dx,$ ? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Why $$
 f(k)=f(k)\int_k^{k+1}1\,dx=\int_k^{k+1}f(k)\,dx\ge \int_{k}^{k+1} f(x)\,dx?
$$ Which equality or inequality you want me to explain?

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n = f(1) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(f(k+1) - \int_k^{k+1}f(x)dx\right)$$ and $$f(k+1) - \int_k^{k+1}f(x)dx\leq0$$ since $f(x)$ is decreasing. So $a_n$ is decreasing. To prove $a_n$ converges, we only need to show $a_n$ is bounded from below.

Remark that $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(f(k) - \int_k^{k+1}f(x)dx\right) + \int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx$$

$f(k) - \int_k^{k+1}f(x)dx \geq 0$ and $f(x)$ is bounded from below, so $a_n$ is greater than the lower bound of $f(x)$